# Changing DD-WRT's default IP address

Tags: networking, ip, router, dd-wrt

I have Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH wireless router and I updated the firmware to DD-WRT (the newest build). The rest of my home network is in IP scope of 192.168.0.100-200 and this router has it's own. The default IP of the router is 192.168.1.1. On the setup tab (Basic setup) there is a place where I can change the IP, gateway etc. If I set the correct configuration, press save and apply, nothing happens, or actually something happens... I have to remove the WAN cable and reset the modem to access it again. So it won't change the IP.

Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is doing nothing? If you are changing the IP, when the appliance changes the IP, the URL you have entered is no longer valid, and active AJAX connections will fail calling the same IP. After you make the change, wait about 30 sec, then punch in the IP you assigned into the address bar and reload.

Comment: No luck. When I type in the new IP and hit apply I will lost the connection immediately. No wired, no wireless. Can't access the old or the new IP.